# Convert apng to gif with sufficiant resolution and color depth

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, animated-gif, fireworks, apng

I want to convert some animated PNG (APNG) images to animated GIF. I can successfully convert with a utility I found on the web called [apng2gif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apng2gif). Expertly named if I may say. The problem is it does not convert the images with sufficient color depth so the output is a little bit to pixelated and not so smooth relative to the original.

Does anyone know of any other image converters that might convert APNG to GIF with more that 16 bit color depth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with the converter, but with GIF format itself:

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format

The format supports up to 8 bits per pixel thus allowing a single image to reference a palette of up to 256 distinct colors.

Comment: The [animated PNG file](http://imgur.com/co4bs) I want to convert come out like [this GIF](http://imgur.com/XLdWv) using the apng2gif utility.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The [animated PNG file](http://imgur.com/co4bs) I want to convert come out like [this GIF](http://imgur.com/XLdWv) using the apng2gif utility. Would you have any opinion on whether I could post process the GIF file for example to sharpen the GIF and make it more like the original. I'm wondering perhaps if apng2gif uses a palette per frame. I think I'll check the source if available.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the GIF to blend better with the background, click on Settings button in apng2gif and then choose the background color you want.

Comment: Excellent. That works perfectly. Blended it in nicely and smooth with a black background.     Command line: apng2gif loading-green.png loading-green.gif /b 0 0 0